# Retrieve the selected value in a select box in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have cascading select boxes with values being populated using `ng-options` from a JSON file.

The HTML code is as below.

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Target Audience</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-pad-fix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Region:</label>
        <select id="region" class="form-control" ng-model="cities" ng-options="region for (region, cities) in dataList">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-pad-fix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">City:</label>
        <select id="city" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="resellers" ng-options="city for (city, resellers) in cities">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-pad-fix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Reseller:</label>
        <select id="reseller" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!cities || !resellers" ng-model="stores" ng-options="reseller for (reseller, stores) in resellers">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-pad-fix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Store:</label>
        <select id="store" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!cities || !resellers || !stores" ng-model="salesTeams" ng-options="store for (store, salesTeams) in stores">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-pad-fix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Sales Team:</label>
        <select id="salesTeam" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!cities || !resellers || !stores || !salesTeams" ng-model="dealers" ng-options="salesTeam for salesTeam in salesTeams">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The controller code is as below

```
angular.module('App.controllers', [])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope, mainAPIservice) {
        $scope.dataList = [];

        mainAPIservice.getData().success(function (response) {
            $scope.dataList = response;
        })

});
```

The services code is as below

```
app.factory('mainAPIservice', function($http) {

    var mainAPI = {};

    mainAPI.getData = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: 'data/data.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
      });
    }

    return mainAPI;
  });
```

Following is the JSON data structure.

```
{  
   "North":{  
      "Delhi":{  
         "Delhi R1":{  
            "Delhi R1 S1":[  
               "Delhi R1 S1 ST1",
               "Delhi R1 S1 ST2",
               "Delhi R1 S1 ST3",
               "Delhi R1 S1 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R1 S2":[  
               "Delhi R1 S2 ST1",
               "Delhi R1 S2 ST2",
               "Delhi R1 S2 ST3",
               "Delhi R1 S2 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R1 S3":[  
               "Delhi R1 S3 ST1",
               "Delhi R1 S3 ST2",
               "Delhi R1 S3 ST3",
               "Delhi R1 S3 ST4"
            ]
         },
         "Delhi R2":{  
            "Delhi R2 S1":[  
               "Delhi R2 S1 ST1",
               "Delhi R2 S1 ST2",
               "Delhi R2 S1 ST3",
               "Delhi R2 S1 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R2 S2":[  
               "Delhi R2 S2 ST1",
               "Delhi R2 S2 ST2",
               "Delhi R2 S2 ST3",
               "Delhi R2 S2 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R2 S3":[  
               "Delhi R2 S3 ST1",
               "Delhi R2 S3 ST2",
               "Delhi R2 S3 ST3",
               "Delhi R2 S3 ST4"
            ]
         },
         "Delhi R3":{  
            "Delhi R3 S1":[  
               "Delhi R3 S1 ST1",
               "Delhi R3 S1 ST2",
               "Delhi R3 S1 ST3",
               "Delhi R3 S1 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R3 S2":[  
               "Delhi R3 S2 ST1",
               "Delhi R3 S2 ST2",
               "Delhi R3 S2 ST3",
               "Delhi R3 S2 ST4"
            ],
            "Delhi R3 S3":[  
               "Delhi R3 S3 ST1",
               "Delhi R3 S3 ST2",
               "Delhi R3 S3 ST3",
               "Delhi R3 S3 ST4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Jaipur":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Lucknow":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Kanpur":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "West":{  
      "Mumbai":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Ahmedabad":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Pune":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Nagpur":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "South":{  
      "Bengaluru":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Hyderabad":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Chennai":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      },
      "Kochi":{  
         "Reseller1":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller2":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         },
         "Reseller3":{  
            "Store1":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store2":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ],
            "Store3":[  
               "Sales Team1",
               "Sales Team2",
               "Sales Team3",
               "Sales Team4"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The cascading select boxes are working fine with appropriate data being populated.  Now, when I submit the form, I need to send the selected values in these select boxes to the backend API.  But I cannot figure out how to retrieve the selected value.  Can anyone please help me out?  Thanks in advance!

Here's the plunkr I have created http://embed.plnkr.co/y2ZtbKlOfhtejVobUzHF/preview

Comment: Could you create a small plunker that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @DeborahK: Please find the plunkr here - http://embed.plnkr.co/y2ZtbKlOfhtejVobUzHF/preview